# Como imprimir los elementos de un archivo al reves?

Tags: c++

Hice un codigo que lee un archivo de texto donde hay solo nombres, los cuales estan separados por un salto de linea, para posteriormente cuando corra el programa me pida que ingrese un caracter especifico y si encuentra el caracter dentro de la palabra que esta en el archivo, lo reescriba en otro archivo llamado Ruta2.txt

Mi pregunta es sobre como puedo imprimir los nombres que estan dentro de este archivo  Ruta2.txt en orden descendente, me explico que sea el ultimo elemento con el que encontro coincidencia aparezca primero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool existe(char car, string cad, int p) {
    if (p == cad.length())return false;
    else if (car == cad.at(p))return true;
    else return existe(car, cad, p + 1);
}

void contiene(char letra) {
    string texto;
    ifstream file;
    ofstream file2;
    int p;
    file.open("Ruta.txt");
    file2.open("Ruta2.txt");
    if (file.good()) {
        if (file2.good()) {
            do
            {
                file >> texto;
                if (existe(letra, texto, p) == true) {
                    cout << texto << endl;
                    file2 << texto << endl;
                }
            } while (!file.eof());

            file.close();
        }
        file2.close();
    }
    else { cout << "No se pudo leer el archivo..."; }
}
int main() {
    char letra;
    cout << "Ingrese letra a buscar en archivos: ";
    cin >> letra;
    contiene(letra);
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();

}
```

Comment: La verdad no lo comprendí muy bien, ¿podrías mostrar un ejemplo?

Comment: El archivo "Ruta.txt" tiene los elementos: casa, celeste, carro, arbol, teclado. Si ingreso a buscar la letra 'e', en el archivo "Ruta2.txt" escribe: celeste, teclado pero en ese orden y claramente separados por saltos de linea en vez de comas.

Comment: Lo que buscaba era imprimirlos en orden descendente osea en vez de celeste, teclado, imprimir teclado y celeste

Comment: Se me ocurren varias opciones. Una podría ser que cuando encuentres las palabras en el primer fichero, en vez de escribirlas en el segundo fichero, las guardes en un (vector, lista, lo que sea), y al terminar, recorras esa lista desde el final y las vayas guardando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, estás reinventando la rueda: No necesitas crear una función para buscar si una cadena contiene un carácter, [dicha función ya existe](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

En segundo lugar, tu código es excesivamente complicado para lo que necesitas hacer. Te aconsejo seguir el consejo de [SuperG280](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/310860/2742) pero con mucho menos código:

```
void contiene(char letra) {
    std::list<std::string> palabras;
    std::string palabra;

    for (std::istream fichero{"Ruta.txt"}; fichero; std::getline(fichero, palabra)) {
        palabras.push_back(palabra);
    }

    if (std::ofstream salida{"Ruta2.txt"}) {
        std::for_each(palabras.rbegin(), palabras.rend(), [&](const std::string &p) {
            if (p.find(letra) != std::string::npos)
                salida << p << '\n';
        });
    }
}
```

Los flujos de datos de entrada y salida (*istream* y *ostream*) son convertibles implícitamente a booleano, obteniendo un valor falso si están en estado erróneo (el fichero no existe, no se pudo leer/escribir), por eso el bucle:

```
for (std::istream fichero{"Ruta.txt"}; fichero; std::getline(fichero, palabra)) {
    palabras.push_back(palabra);
}
```

Puede interpretarse como "*Abre `Ruta.txt` y mientras esté abierto, lee líneas hasta que no haya nada más que leer*".

```
//   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--- Abre Ruta.txt
for (std::istream fichero{"Ruta.txt"}; fichero; std::getline(fichero, palabra)) {
//                                     ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Lee una líne de 'fichero' y guárdala en 'palabra'
//                                        \ 
//                                         \_ <--- Mientras esté abierto y con contenido
    palabras.push_back(palabra);
}
```

Cada palabra leída la guardamos en una lista (`std::list`) porque es una estructura con mucha eficiencia para añadir datos (por el contrario, `std::vector` es muy eficiente para recorrer datos pero ineficiente para añadirlos).

Finalmente aplicamos una función a todo el rango con [`std::for_each` de `<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), recorriéndolo a la inversa. Para recorrerlo a la inversa usamos iteradores inversos ([`rbegin` y `rend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin): *reverse begin* y *reverse end* respectivamente):

```
//      Del final ---> vvvvvv             vvvv <--- Al principio
std::for_each(palabras.rbegin(), palabras.rend(), [&](const std::string &p) {
    if (p.find(letra) != std::string::npos)
        salida << p << '\n';
});
```

La función aplicada al rango es una Lambda que simplemente inyecta la palabra en el archivo de salida cuando la palabra contiene la letra facilitada.

Answer (score 3):

Como te decía en un comentario, se me ocurre usar un vector para guardar las líneas y luego escribirlas en el fichero con un iterador desde el final. Tu función contiene cambia un poco porque ya no hace falta manejar el segundo fichero hasta que no hayas terminado de leer el primero. Podría ser algo así:

```
void contiene(char letra) {
    string texto;
    ifstream file;
    ofstream file2;
    vector<string> coincidencias;

    int p = 0;
    file.open("Ruta.txt");

    if (file.good()) {

        do
        {
            file >> texto;
            if (existe(letra, texto, p) == true) {
                cout << texto << endl;
                //file2 << texto << endl;
                coincidencias.push_back(texto);
            }
            texto = ""; //Si no la inicializo, la última palabra se incluye dos veces

        } while (!file.eof());

        file.close();

        file2.open("Ruta2.txt");
        if (file2.good()) {
            for (std::vector<string>::reverse_iterator it = coincidencias.rbegin(); it != coincidencias.rend(); it++) {
                file2 << *it << endl;
            }

        }
        file2.close();

    } else {
        cout << "No se pudo leer el archivo...";
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<string>::reverse_iterator it = coincidencias.rbegin()` es terriblemente verboso. ¿Por qué no usar `auto`?: `auto b = coincidencias.rbegin(), e = coincidencias.rend()`

Comment: Inicialmente lo puse como auto, pero consideré más instructivo usar toda la nomenclatura en este ejemplo. No soy muy partidario de los autos porque considero más difícil de mantener en el futuro.

Comment: Pues yo opino que te equivocas, el exceso de verbosidad no hace el código más legible si no menos y el uso de `auto` no decrementa la mantenibilidad si no que la aumenta. Y [no soy el único que lo piensa](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta. Gracias por el aporte!!!